# Biztalk schema variable number of columns in delimited file permitted?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

Hiyas.  I have a customer sending orders to us in a flat file.  There isn't really any complexity to the file but there are some inconsistencies from file to file.

The format of the file is like this:

1,2,3[CRLF]
1,2,3[CRLF]

No problems creating a schema around that structure, however from time to time they will add a new column.

1,2,3,**4**[CRLF]
1,2,3,**4**[CRLF]

Unfortunatly, they don't make their changes cascade backwards so we hare expected to support both the 3 and 4 column formats.  Both formats can potentially come through the same pipeline, so i don't really have the option of creating seperate schemas/pipelines.  They do always add the new fields to the end of the row, so that much at least is consistent.

The only thiing i can think of to do is to create an elaborate "figure out which schema applies and route accordingly pipeline component", but before I go down that road I wanted to see if maybe anyone had some thoughts on way to make it work with a single flat file schema (I tried to set the minOccurs property of the optional columns to 0, but that was no good).

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Is there anything that would identify the different types of records at the front of the record? If there was, you could use a tag identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to define a "outer" schema and **import schemas for the different versions** you need to support. The "outer" schema will offer a `choice` block containing references to your imported version schemas.

If you need to add the next version you just have to import a new schema and add it to the `choice`.

The hard part of course is how you can determine how to process different versions. Maybe the simplest way would be to create a map for every dedicated type you need to handle. On the other hand you could extend a "latest-and-greatest" internal message type and decide based on message content.

**"outer" schema**

```
<!-- language: xml-schema -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:ns0="http://ACME.Version_001" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns="http://ACME.Outer" xmlns:ns1="http://ACME.Version_002" targetNamespace="http://ACME.Outer" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:import schemaLocation=".\version_002.xsd" namespace="http://ACME.Version_002" />
    <xs:import schemaLocation=".\version_001.xsd" namespace="http://ACME.Version_001" />
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" root_reference="Root" />
            <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
            <b:references>
                <b:reference targetNamespace="http://ACME.Version_001" />
                <b:reference targetNamespace="http://ACME.Version_002" />
            </b:references>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" sequence_number="1" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_order="postfix" child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" />
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="1">
                    <xs:element ref="ns0:Version_001">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:appinfo>
                                <b:recordInfo sequence_number="1" structure="delimited" />
                            </xs:appinfo>
                        </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element ref="ns1:Version_002">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:appinfo>
                                <b:recordInfo sequence_number="2" structure="delimited" />
                            </xs:appinfo>
                        </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Imported schema "Version_001"**

```
<!-- language: xml-schema -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns="http://ACME.Version_001" targetNamespace="http://ACME.Version_001" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" root_reference="Version_001" />
            <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
        </xs:appinfo>
   </xs:annotation>
   <xs:element name="Version_001">
       <xs:annotation>
           <xs:appinfo>
               <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_order="infix" rootTypeName="Version_001" child_delimiter="," />
           </xs:appinfo>
       </xs:annotation>
       <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element name="Col1" type="xs:string" />
               <xs:element name="Col2" type="xs:string" />
               <xs:element name="Col3" type="xs:string" />
           </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Imported schema "Version_002"**

```
<!-- language: xml-schema -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns="http://ACME.Version_002" targetNamespace="http://ACME.Version_002" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" root_reference="Version_002" />
            <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
        </xs:appinfo>
   </xs:annotation>
   <xs:element name="Version_002">
       <xs:annotation>
           <xs:appinfo>
               <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_order="infix" rootTypeName="Version_001" child_delimiter="," />
           </xs:appinfo>
       </xs:annotation>
       <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element name="Col1" type="xs:string" />
               <xs:element name="Col2" type="xs:string" />
               <xs:element name="Col3" type="xs:string" />
               <xs:element name="Col4" type="xs:string" />
           </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

*(some default attributes omitted for readability)*

Comment: Thanks Filburt, the "choice' schema sounds like the best solutiion.